# Use prepared statement in query with 'IN(.....)' clause?

Tags: php, pdo

Is there a (tricky/non-standard) way to do this?

Would something like

```
$stmt = $db->prepare( 'SELECT title FROM episode WHERE id IN (?, ?, ?, ?);
```

work? So if I wanted to search for a variable amount of ids, could I do

```
$ids = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
$idSection = implode(array_pad(array(), count($ids), '?')) //To give ?,?,?,?,?,?,?
$stmt = $db->prepare( 'SELECT title FROM episode WHERE id IN ($idSection);
$stmp->execute($ids);
```

Even if that would work, it still isn't really useful for running multiple sets of data with the same prepared statement unless the set of `$ids` being searched for is the same length every time and it doesn't work with name placeholders.

I'm assuming if you do

```
$stmt = $db->prepare( 'SELECT title FROM episode WHERE id IN (:ids);
$ids = implode('","' array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7));
$stmt->bindParam( ':ids', $ids);
```

It fails because the prepared statement was constructed so that it will search for a single id value and "1","2","3","4","5","6","7" wouldn't match?

I'm sure there's a better answer than just not using `IN(...)` clauses. Would I just have to sanitize the `$ids` term manually and include it in the query without placeholders?

```
$stmt = $db->prepare( "SELECT title FROM episode WHERE id IN $ids AND genre like :genre");
$stmt->bindParam( ':genre', '%$genre%);
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A way to avoid using IN-clauses is to populate a temporary table with the values that would go into the IN( ... ) as a comma-separated list; then either INNER-JOIN on the temp-table's column or do a nested-select:

```
        inner join temptable T2 on T1.mycol = T2.col1
```

OR

```
       ...  where mycol in ( Select col1 from temptable)
```

Comment: That's a good idea! But since I'm trying to do things the 'prepared way' then I either have to run a prepared multi-insert statement to build the temporary table (which runs into the same type of issue), or run a prepared single-insert statement multiple times. I know running a prepared single-insert multiple times should be faster than running a regular single-insert multiple times, but would it still be significantly slower than a multi-insert?

Comment: Depends on the number of rows, but running a prepared statement multiple times is the better practice. You could pass a simple delimited string to a stored procedure on the server, which extracts the constituent values from the string and does the inserts into the temp table.

Answer (score 10):

MySql has a FIND_IN_SET function, which you can use to achieve the same result:

```
$ids = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
$stmt = $db->prepare( 'SELECT title FROM episode WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id,?)' );
$param = implode(',',$ids);
$stmt->bind_param('s',$param); 
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: And remember, FIND_IN_SET is very slow in compare with IN clause